# Excel time between two timestamps

Tags: excel, timestamp, intervals

I have the following time stamps in Excel, and i want to calculate the time (in seconds) between these two intervalls.

```
Start: 2016-07-15 13:39:41.602553
End:   2016-07-15 13:42:52.597283
```

> (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ffffff)

The start value is in cell A1 and the end value is in cell B1.
The cells are currently formated as "General" which might be wrong, so they are not as per definition timestamps.

I have tried:

```
=Int(B1)-Int(A1)
=B1-A1
```

But it won't do the job (half expected)

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Some clarifications

Best regards,
VD

Comment: Thank you, i don't have a workaround. I just have the time stamps and need a formula to tell me the time difference in seconds. I have tried to clarify the original post.

Comment: Do you just have the times in A1 and B1?  Or do you also have the words `Start: ` and `End: `?

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be the solution for this question:

=(DATEVALUE(LEFT(B1;10))+TIMEVALUE(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B1;”.”;”,”);12;8))-(DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1;10))+TIMEVALUE(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1;”.”;”,”);12;8))

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try and make your question a bit clearer and include what you've tried to achieve this and I'd imagine people won't downvote you so quickly (not me btw).

If you have your start and end in two cells (A1 and A2) then the difference in seconds is `=VALUE(TEXT(A2-A1,"[s]"))`

Comment: So have you tried what I put in (though you're using A1 and B1 instead of my assumptions) or is that not what you're after? It correctly returns the number of whole seconds even if over 60.

Comment: I have tried it but i'm getting a value error.
Do i have to use a specific format in the data cells in order for it to work?

Comment: Are the timestamps there as text? That would give you those sorts of issues.

Comment: The timestamps would almost have to be text since they are showing more than three decimals in the seconds field

Comment: In that case you'd have to use TIMEVALUE() round the A1 and B1

Comment: If you are using it in a mathematical formula, as both of us did, Excel should convert it automatically.  I suspect there is some other issue which is interfering with the OP's calculations

Answer (score 0):

Excel stores dates and times as days (since 1 Jan 1900) and fractions of a day.  So you were pretty close.

```
=B1-A1  and format result as [s]
```

or  (there are 86400 seconds in a day)

```
=ROUND((B1-A1)*86400,0)
```

Here is a screenshot.
The timestamps are formatted as `General`, but they are text strings; the first formula as `[s]`, and the second as `General`

[image]